# Incheon free transit tour: no slots in online reservation for my tour choice. Can I still join on-site?

Tags: transit, south-korea

If the schedule for my particular choice of tour (slots show 15/15) is full in the reservation website, do I still have a chance to join that tour when registering on-site (off-line without reservation) as soon as possible when I arrive in Korea?

Do they only have 1 bus for that particular tour and how many passengers does it accommodate? I just want to know if there'll be more people given a chance aside from those people who reserved in advance. Because other tours seem short and not fit for my flight schedule, so I wanted to know if I'll still have the chance to visit that place e.g. tradition tour. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had booked a 2 hour temple tour for my layover at Incheon in early January, 2018. They seem to have since updated the schedule, as I do not see that tour on their website anymore. When I arrived at the counter, I was told that my particular tour had been cancelled. I was lucky, though, and they still had one last free slot in a different tour.

The bus I took looked like this:

[image: bus from outside] [image: bus from inside]

Every seat was occupied, so the capacity for spontaneous arrivals seems to be pretty limited. They also only had one bus and one guide for each tour. I do not think they can just get additional ones on short notice.

If you have the time and do not mind the immigration procedure and security check afterwards, you might go ahead and hope some people that registered do not show up. The tour guides and employees were very friendly, if a bit disorganized, and will probably do everything to somehow accommodate you. Do not expect to get into a tour if all the registered participants actually come, though.